# Play example from documentation results in "Invalid Content-Type"

Tags: twilio

The example is found in documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/play

The example on the site is:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let actions = [];
    let play = {
        "play":
             {
                "loop": 2,
                "url": "https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3"
             }
       }

    actions.push(play);
    let respObj = {
        "actions": actions
    };
    callback(null, respObj);    
};
```

If you test it, it results in an error that shows in the debugger as: `Invalid Content-Type`.

When I call it to test it says "we're sorry, an application error has occured. good bye"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested out the example above and it works. Are you pointing Autopilot to this `Actions URL`? The red arrow points to the URL/PATH of your Twilio Function. [image]